# Syntax highlighting tool for Objective C compatible for Google sites?

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, syntax-highlighting, google-sites

I'm using Google Sites to share/store useful code snippets. Can anyone show me how I can make my code snippets look like [this](http://classroomm.com/objective-c/index.php?topic=2761.0) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd check out [GeSHi, the Generic Syntax Highlighter](http://qbnz.com/highlighter). It has pretty good support for Objective C. I don't know if it'll work with Google Sites, though.